# This code keeps formatting the file instead of writing to it. How do i fix it?

Tags: java, arrays, java-io, formatter

I have declared an array and and variables up here. productList array, name, price and number

```js
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadingAndWritting {

  public String name;
  public double price;
  public int number;
  public ReadingAndWritting[] productList = new ReadingAndWritting[3];

  public ReadingAndWritting() {

  }

  public ReadingAndWritting(String name, double price, int number) {

    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.number = number;

  }

  public void printContents() {

    int i = 0;

    try {

      FileReader fl = new FileReader("Product List.txt");

      Scanner scn = new Scanner(fl);

      while (scn.hasNext()) {

        String productName = scn.next();

        double productPrice = scn.nextDouble();

        int productAmount = scn.nextInt();

        System.out.println(productName + " is " + productPrice + " pula. There are " + productAmount + " items left in stalk.");

        productList[i] = new ReadingAndWritting(productName, productPrice, productAmount);

        i = i + 1;

      }

      scn.close();

    } catch (IOException exc) {

      exc.printStackTrace();

    } catch (Exception exc) {

      exc.printStackTrace();

    }

  }

  public void writeContents() {

    try {

      //FileOutputStream formater = new FileOutputStream("Product List.txt",true);

      Formatter writer = new Formatter(new FileOutputStream("Product List.txt", true));

      for (int i = 0; i < productList.length; ++i) {

        writer.format(name, (price + 100.0), (number - 1), "\n");

      }

      writer.close();

    } catch (IOException exc) {

      exc.printStackTrace();

    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ReadingAndWritting obj = new ReadingAndWritting();

    System.out.println("_____THIS IS THE BEGINNING OF THE PRODUCT LIST_____");

    obj.printContents();

    System.out.println("_____THIS IS THE END OF THE PRODUCT LIST_____");

    System.out.println("_____THIS IS THE BEGINNING OF THE PRODUCT LIST_____");

    obj.writeContents();

    obj.printContents();

    System.out.println("_____THIS IS THE END OF THE PRODUCT LIST_____");

  }

}
```

Every time i run the code it keeps formatting the existing file and then reporting a NullPointerException. I am completely lost as to how to fix this and our lecturer never covered it. Please

> > the productList[] array has name,price and number value contained in each identifier. I want to wipe the contents of the existing file and then write with the new values to update contents from the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor you are using truncates the input file, as clearly stated in the Javadoc :

> **fileName** The name of the file to use as the destination of this formatter. If the file exists then it will be **truncated to zero size**; otherwise, a new file will be created. The output will be written to the file and is buffered.

You can use other constructors, such as `Formatter(OutputStream os)` to avoid that truncation.

```
Formatter writer = new Formatter(new FileOutputStream("Product List.txt",true));
```

As for the `NullPointerException`, seeing your comment of :

```
 public String name;
```

`name` is not initialized, so it is `null` by default, which leads to the `NullPointerException`.

P.S. I don't know what `productList` is, by based on its name and the fact that you are iterating over it, perhaps you should get the `price` and `name` from the elements of that list.

EDIT :

Based on the rest of your code, you should take the values from the `productList` array :

```
  for (int i = 0; i < productList.length; ++i) {

    writer.format(productList[i].name, (productList[i].price + 100.0), (productList[i].number - 1), "\n");

  }
```

Comment: I added the full code... how about now? what is the reason for the NullPointerException?

Answer (score 0):

```
writer.format(name, (price + 100.0), (number - 1), "\n");
```

has the incorrect parameters. Due to which its giving the NullPointerException.
Read the Java doc to know about the correct parameters that should be passed.

Do something like this:

```
public String str=null; //declare class variable str.
```

In the printContents() method assign the following to the string:

```
str = "\n"+productName +" "+ (productPrice + 100.0)+" "+ (productAmount -   1)+"\n";
```

And then finally method, change the parameters being passed to writer.format() method like this:

```
Formatter writer = new Formatter(new FileOutputStream("Product List.txt", true));

  for (int i = 0; i < productList.length; ++i) {

    writer.format(str);
  }
```

This is working for me.
The value you want is getting properly appended in the file "ProductList.txt".